# Stop Firefox from adding pragma and cache headers to XMLHTTP Req?

Tags: firefox, caching, pragma, xmlhttprequest

I've written an extension that sends XHR POSTs, but two headers are being added that I don't want:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I've read that someone else with this problem had turned off their cache in developer tools, but I don't recall doing this, and for all I can tell caching should be enabled.

What might be adding these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is adding those headers.  The relevant code comment is:

```
// Bypass the network cache in cases where it makes no sense:
// POST responses are always unique, and we provide no API that would
// allow our consumers to specify a "cache key" to access old POST
// responses, so they are not worth caching.
```

That code was added in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295074

Comment: Thank you. I don't see these headers with POSTs sent from webpage forms, but I suppose XHRs just work differently.

Comment: POSTs from web page forms make sense to cache: you can then use the cached version for things like "view source" and "save page".